# react testing library is not mocking inner child axios call

Tags: reactjs, axios, jestjs, mocking, react-testing-library

It is a simple question if someone has encountered it. Let us have two-component A and B. A is the parent of B. B has an Axios call in useEffect. When I am testing A and it successfully rendered B in it, but Axios call is not firing or mocking.
Also, I have a separate Test for B in which Axios call is getting fired and mocked. There is no condition on Axios call in B, if B renders, Axios call must be fired.
If someone has some idea please answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have tests for "B" component, you can mock it in your "A" test. something like this:

```
jest.mock("/path/to/B/component", ()=>()=><div>Some test text</div>)
```

then you can do:

```
it("should render B component",()=>{
    const wrapper = render(<A></A>)
    expect(wrapper.getByText("Some test text")).toBeInTheDocument();
})
```

Comment: but it already render B component when rendering A. @punjira

Comment: Yes but you mentioned that you have already tested your B component, so why not just mock it as a div?

Comment: I have no answer for it. When I am testing Parent component, axios call can't fired or mocked axios call can't fired, which is in Child component.
I am adding this for reference. If someone find answer, please submit below.
Thanks for help.